# Asyncronous variables outside a for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, asynchronous, for-loop

I'm just starting out with AJAX and I'm trying to get a variable to be set inside a for loop. Then I want to call that variable later and use it's value.

Of course this would be synchronous, requiring the scripts to stop executing in order to run the loop before returning the new value of the function.

I'm hoping someone knows a better way to get the value from the for loop AFTER the for loop has run and use it in my code directly after that.

I would prefer not to use the `setTimeout()` hack to bypass this issue (it is a hack after all).

```
var getCount = function getCount(res) {
    count = { active: 0, closed: 0 }; //Variable defined here

    for(i=0; i<=res.length; i++) {
        if(res[i].status == 'active') {
            count.active ++;
        } else { count.closed ++; }
    }
    return count; //And returned here
};

getCount(result);

console.log(count); //Here's where I need the result of the for loop

//Currently this outputs the count object with both properties set to 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what AJAX has to do with your issue.

You are not assigning the result of the getCount function to the count variable (Unless you intended the count variable to be global, but in that case you need to define it before the getCount function definition).

Change this line:

```
getCount(result);
```

to this:

```
var count = getCount(result);
```

And you should be alright. :)

I would also suggest, when declaring variables, always declare them with var. In your case:

```
var count = { active: 0, closed: 0};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you mention AJAX since there is nothing async about your code.
From what I see in your sample I don't see what all the difficulty is about.

Just use it as any other function.

```
function getCount(res) {
    var count = { active: 0, closed: 0 }; //Variable defined here

    for(i=0; i<=res.length; i++) {
        if(res[i].status == 'active') {
            count.active ++;
        } else { count.closed ++; }
    }
    return count; //And returned here
};

console.log(getCount(result)); //Here's where I need the result of the for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you had an extra `=` sign that was over-extending your `for` loop. I don't know if this answers your asynchronous issue, but here is how I would do it:

```
// sample object
var result = [
  {status:"active"},
  {status:"not-active"},
  {status:"active"} 
];

// kick off the function to get the count object back
var counts = getCount(result);

console.log(counts);


function getCount(res) {
    var count = { active: 0, closed: 0 }; //Variable defined here, make sure you have var to keep it from going global scope

    for(i=0; i<res.length; i++) { //here you had a wrong "="
        if(res[i].status === 'active') {
            count.active ++;
        } else { count.closed ++; }
    }
    return count; //And returned here
}
```

Example [here](http://jsbin.com/ocajon/1/edit).